How to assign the 'And' value in Azure Costmanagment QueryFilter?
Core question -> How do I filter the Azure CostManagment cost results to 1 day of data?
Currently facing -> How do I assign the 'And' field a value in the QueryFilter?
I have a Azure Function App that will query a number of subscriptions Cost Analysis data and egress it to an Azure DataLakes blob.
I'm aware of the built in portal Export option, however I'm not aware of how this option can be deployed and managed for 100+ subscriptions, and scale out as new subscriptions are enabled.  Additionally you don't have the functionality to filter it down to just the last day.  At best it's WeekToDate.
The app will deploy with the subscriptions, filter the results down to the single day and so on..
Now for the app.
var queryDef = new QueryDefinition(
    ExportType.ActualCost,
    TimeframeType.WeekToDate,
    queryFilter
    );

Simple method,
Then to define the QueryDataset is where I'm getting stuck.
    var queryFilter = new QueryFilter
    {
        And = new List<QueryFilter>                {
            new() {
                Dimensions = new QueryComparisonExpression("string", QueryOperatorType.In, new List<string>())
            },
            new()
            {
                Dimensions = new QueryComparisonExpression("string", QueryOperatorType.In, new List<string>())
            },
        }
    };

    var queryDataset = new QueryDataset
    {
        Filter = queryFilter,
    };

I can't figure out how to appease the QueryFilter requirements, the
And = new List<QueryFilter>   

Line gives me the error

Property or indexer 'QueryFilter.And' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

But in the same error shows

The logical "AND" expression. Must have at least 2 items.

I see in the QueryFilter class that the And field is in fact read only,
/// <summary> The logical "AND" expression. Must have at least 2 items. </summary>
public IList<QueryFilter> And { get; }

but then has a constructor
/// <summary> Initializes a new instance of QueryFilter. </summary>
public QueryFilter()
{
    And = new ChangeTrackingList<QueryFilter>();
    Or = new ChangeTrackingList<QueryFilter>();
}

So I'm guessing I'm missing on how to do the construction on this class? maybe?

Please edit your question and include your code and the error you are getting.

@GauravMantri done, was fighting with the sites parser which was telling me I needed more spaces ><!

Use a QueryTimePeriod to define a custom date range for the cost query, instead of relying on the built-in TimeframeType.


So I'm guessing I'm missing on how to do the construction on this class? maybe?


In Azure Cost Management's QueryFilter, the And property is read-only, meaning you can't assign a value directly like And = .... Instead, you need to add items to the And list because it's initialized within the constructor. You can do this by creating individual QueryFilter instances and adding them to the And list.

Code:
// Create individual query filters
var filter1 = new QueryFilter
{
    Dimensions = new QueryComparisonExpression
    (
        "ResourceGroupName", // Dimension name
        QueryOperatorType.In,
        new List<string> { "YourResourceGroup1", "YourResourceGroup2" } // Values to filter
    )
};

var filter2 = new QueryFilter
{
    Dimensions = new QueryComparisonExpression
    (
        "ResourceType", // Another dimension name
        QueryOperatorType.In,
        new List<string> { "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" }
    )
};

// Initialize the main filter and add these to the 'And' collection
var queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
queryFilter.And.Add(filter1);
queryFilter.And.Add(filter2);

// Now you can use this queryFilter in your query definition
var queryDataset = new QueryDataset
{
    Filter = queryFilter,
    Granularity = GranularityType.Daily // Optional: specify granularity
};

var queryDef = new QueryDefinition
{
    Type = ExportType.ActualCost,
    Dataset = queryDataset
};

// Now queryDef is ready to be used in the cost query.


The And property is a list of QueryFilter objects. It add individual QueryFilter instances to the And collection using Add().

Each QueryFilter can contain a comparison expression based on a dimension (e.g., ResourceGroupName, ResourceType), and you can use operators like In to filter specific values.


Here is the result you get back in a JSON structure with details:
{
    "Columns": [
        {"Name": "ResourceGroupName", "Type": "string"},
        {"Name": "ResourceType", "Type": "string"},
        {"Name": "Cost", "Type": "number"},
        {"Name": "Date", "Type": "datetime"}
    ],
    "Rows": [
        ["YourResourceGroup1", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines", 120.50, "2024-10-10"],
        ["YourResourceGroup2", "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines", 200.75, "2024-10-10"]
    ]
}

